# Knockout JSON not updating

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

In the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xa9ez/

There's a variable called jsonData which uses the KO function toJSON.

Why does it not update when the other variables are updated?
Or even when the goCaps function is called?

Script:

```
function AppViewModel() {

    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
    }, this);

    this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
        var currentVal = this.lastName();        // Read the current value
        this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());

        this.data = ko.toJSON(this);

    };    
    this.data = ko.toJSON(this);
}
var appViewModel = new AppViewModel()
// Activates knockout.js


ko.applyBindings(appViewModel );
```

Html

```
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
<p>JSON: <strong data-bind="text: data"></strong></p>
​
```

Comment: `this.data` does not seem to be an observable.

Comment: How can I make it an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make `this.data` observable:

```
function AppViewModel() {

    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
    }, this);

    this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
        var currentVal = this.lastName();        // Read the current value
        this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());

        this.data(ko.toJSON(this));

    };    
    this.data = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(this));
}
```

[More about observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).